# Sinonimo di non affidabile, fannullone, mai preciso

Tags: synonym

Cerco un "sinonimo", se esiste, che racchiuda un po' di tutti i seguenti concetti: persona poco affidabile, che non vuole fare niente, che non è mai precisa, che punta sempre alla sufficienza..

(e, se lo avete, l'equivalente in Inglese)

Edit: forse "cialtrone" che i dizionari mi propongono in inglese come "scoundrel"? Però questo sembra avere una connotazione etico/intenzionale "volgare,spregevole, arrogante,imbroglione" che qui non intendo..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Una possibilità è ***scioperato***
che comprende sia l'essere senza voglia di lavorare che un modo di vivere disordinato.

https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/scioperato/

https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/scioperato_(Sinonimi-e-Contrari)/

Anche ***scombinato***, che il vocabolario Treccani definisce come 'persona strana, disordinata e priva di coerenza, che dà poco affidamento'.
C'è meno l'aspetto di mancanza di voglia di lavorare.

https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/scombinato/

Più forte è ***sciamannato***:

https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sciamannato/

calca sulla trascuratezza e il disordine, l'inaffidabilità, si può dire anche del disordine esteriore nell'abbigliamento.
È un po' più forte, più dispregiativo di *scombinato*.

https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sciamannato/

Si potrebbe anche dire ***buono a nulla***, che è un incapace, inetto, fannullone.

https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ricerca/buono-a-nulla/Sinonimi_e_Contrari/

Poi di sinonimi di *fannullone*, persona che non ha voglia di fare niente, ce ne sono vari, da *scansafatiche*, a *infingardo*, etc., ma non racchiudono i vari significati che hai elencato.